# Iterate the children of Array of objects -ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

guys I am making `<table>` for the result of my array objects, but I encountered problem of iterating the children of the array objects.
This is my data (`this.props.converted` value):
[image here, value of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huAiK.png)

```
<table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Contact Numbers</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Birthdate</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>            
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.converted.map((data,idx) =>( //Please check the image above for my data
                    <tr key={idx}>
                    <td>
                    {data.children.map(data => data).join(', ')}
                    </td>
                    <td>{data.contact_number}</td>
                    <td>{data.Address}</td>
                    <td>{data.Email}</td>
                    <td>{data.Birthdate}</td>
                    <td>{data.Note}</td>
                    </tr>
                     ))}
                </tbody>

             </table>
```

Output should something like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjUCH.png)

Comment: I think you have to take a different variable name instead of data in the second iteration of children
{data.children.map(data => data).join(', ')}

instead of data=>data choose other variable names

Comment: What issue or exception you are getting?

Comment: No error, but in the display, it is not displaying the value of it. Check the result here: http://prntscr.com/jrfiny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already discovered the answer by me..

```
    <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Birthdate</th>
                    <th>Note</th>
                    <th>Contact Numbers</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>            
            <tbody>
                {this.props.converted.map((data,idx) =>(
                <tr key={idx}>

                {data.children.map((x,i) => (
                       <td key={i}>{x.value}</td>
                )         
                )}

                <td>{data.contact_number}</td>
                <td>{data.Address}</td>
                <td>{data.Email}</td>
                <td>{data.Birthdate}</td>
                <td>{data.Note}</td>
                </tr>
                 ))}
            </tbody>

         </table>
```